# run Blender 2.49b on Ubuntu 16.04, 64bit

Tags: compatibility

unfortunately the old Blender 2.49b has still some import/export functions that newer versions of blender do not have. So I used this program always besides the newest version of Blender. In the past (until Ubuntu 12.04, 64bit) I had no problem to install old Python 2.6 and than Blender 2.49 worked. Since I work on Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit) I am not able to use old Blender 2.49. Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you describe any more details as to why 2.49b doesn't work? Does it crash on startup? are there any errors in the log?

Comment: up to 12.04 I just installed Python 2.6 than I opened the folder with Blender 2.49b for 64bit and Python 2.6 and clicked on the executable for blender and it worked. Now just nothing happens.